# "No such file or directory" but the file and directory is already included - Eclipse based IDE - c project

Tags: c, eclipse, build, ide

I am having an issue trying to compile an SDK of Semtech in STM32CubeIDE. I am figuring out how to be able compile it and debug it in that IDE because the projects are created only for Keil uVision and as Makefiles using GNU ARM Toolchain.

I have the following error "No such file or directory", but the directory is already included.

```
17:29:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project gnss_test_executable_02 ****
make all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -c -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -fcyclomatic-complexity -MMD -MP -MF"lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.d" -MT"lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -mthumb -o "lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.o"
In file included from ../lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.c:1:
../lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.h:3:10: fatal error: lr11xx_bootloader_types.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "lr11xx_bootloader_types.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [lr11xx/common/printers/subdir.mk:40: lr11xx/common/printers/lr11xx_bootloader_types_str.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

17:29:48 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.298ms)
```

I have imported the file directories of the SDK into my workspace.

I included all the folders that have .h files, including "lr11xx\lr11xx_driver\src" where the file of the error is located.

Could it possibly be an issue related to Macros or Environment Variables?

Thanks in advance, don't hesitate to ask any information you may need.

What I've tried:

I have included the "Includes" directories in my properties in the "C/C++ Build" section.

I also included the file "lr11xx_bootloader_types.h" especifically in the C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MCU GCC Compiler -> Include Paths -> Include files (-include) Section.

I was trying to figure out if it was something related to Macros or Environment Variables but couldn't get a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add paths where **`.h`** files are located.

It is located in the *Project properties* **->** *C/C++ General* **->** *Paths and Symbols* in the *Includes* tab.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering.
I have included the folders where the file under discussion (lr11xx_bootloader_types.h) is located. I also put it separately in the "Include Files" section (directory mentioned in the penultimate sentence of my question) but this couldn't solved the issue.

Comment: @NicolasQuiroga do you know the correct way of saying "thank you" here?

Comment: Hi, in my first comment I pressed the Enter Key to make a break line and I discover that sent the comment. Then I edited it. 
I had tried what you suggest in the answer but the error was still appearing. That's why I wrote this topic, so as to know if there's something I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Then you dont add it properly

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with 2023 09 Eclipse.
Reason is that the gcc takes place in a sub directory that is the named build directory such as "Debug".

I get one to work if I go to an include statement and change from:
folder/header.h
to
../folder/header.h

But this is not desirable to refactor every header include in all source files.
There must be a check box to fix this but no one seems to know.